# `pipeline_job` registered model input

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using the pipeline private preview from CLI (v2).

I'd like to know how to use a registered model as an input of my pipeline.

Similarly to how I access the blob storage:

```yaml
inputs:
  input_data:
    data:
      datastore: azureml:dualcam
      path: /image-20210701*
```

I'm expecting to be able to use my registered model but I can find the schema to add it.

Answer (score 1):

For CLI 2.0+., You should not use the docs from ml(v1) but should just use the ones that say [ml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ml?view=azure-cli-latest).

Here is the [commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ml/model?view=azure-cli-latest) to manage Azure ML models.

https://github.com/Azure/AutoML-vNext-Preview/tree/main/examples/cli